# Asp.net Core JQuery scroll to div on page load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have run up against a little problem. I am trying to get the page to scroll to a specific point on page load but I'm not getting anywhere. The code I have used is below. For some reason it doesn't seem to be running at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // scroll past header on page load
        function scrollToDiv() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var ele = $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#tree').position().top }, 500, 'linear');
            });
        };


        scrollToDiv();

    </script>
```

If you have any suggestions as to why it is not working I would certainly appreciate it.

I am building using ASP.NET Core. The above jQuery code worked on an old webforms project so I have no idea why it isn't working now.

Comment: `$.document.ready(function(){ ... })` fires once, when the DOM has been parsed. Calling it from inside another function is a code-smell. And [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) recommends against using it; the recommended version is `$(function(){ ... })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    const top = $('#tree').position().top;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 500, 'linear');
});
</script>
```

However, you don't need jQuery for this:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const target = document.getElementById('tree');
    target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
});
</script>
```

[Window: DOMContentLoaded event - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)
[Element.scrollIntoView() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time to render assistance in my time of need. Thank you.